# Typescript: How do I use a class or interface from a namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to extend a class defined in the namespace `google.maps` in this file:

> @types/googlemaps/index.d.ts

```
class MyMarker extends google.maps.Marker {
  constructor(options: google.maps.MarkerOptions){
    super(options);
  }
}
```

This transpiles without errors. But on runtime, I get an error in the constructor because the `google.maps` global is still undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u sure that u added google map module?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import it first, for example

```
import Marker from 'googlemaps';

class MyMarker extends Marker
```

Comment: I tried that, but TS gives me an error, `.../@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts is not a module`. It is a namespace and the actual googlemaps lib is loaded dynamically

Answer (score 0):

BTW, my fallback is to use an `interface` instead of `class` and do a bunch of TS typecast gymnastics. It works but it's not optimal...

```
// new google.maps.Marker for MarkerClusterer
export interface UuidMarker extends Marker {
  uuid: string;
}

/**
 * Hack: "extend" google.maps.Marker to include uuid property
 *  guard with this.ready.then() to ensure google.maps is loaded
 */
function UuidMarkerFactory(uuid: string, options?: MarkerOptions) : Promise<UuidMarker> {
  return this.ready.then( ()=>{
    let gmOptions = options as any as google.maps.MarkerOptions;
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker( gmOptions );
    marker['uuid'] = uuid;
    return marker as any as UuidMarker;
  })
}
```